# "No such table" after redeploy

Tags: python, database, heroku, migration, heroku-postgres

I am trying to implement automatic migration in my application. `Procfile` includes:

```
release: python manage.py migrate
...
```

```
2020-08-04T15:01:34.924211+00:00 heroku[run.4178]: State changed from starting to up
2020-08-04T15:01:35.269081+00:00 heroku[run.4178]: Awaiting client
2020-08-04T15:01:35.326202+00:00 heroku[run.4178]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate`
2020-08-04T15:01:44.905287+00:00 heroku[run.4178]: Process exited with status 0
2020-08-04T15:01:44.945348+00:00 heroku[run.4178]: State changed from up to complete
```

However, if I try to load data into database it prints: `No such table: <>` error. It works if I rerun migrate command. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use PostgreSQL

```
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```